# Using primitive operators to find factorial of N up to K depth

Tags: python, while-loop, factorial

Having difficulty coming up with a solution using:

1. iteration/control-flow and
2. accumulation.

More than just a solution, would prefer having an answer with hints and explanation.

```
def falling(n, k):
    """Compute the falling factorial of N to depth K.

    >>> falling(6, 3)  # 6 * 5 * 4
    120
    >>> falling(4, 3)  # 4 * 3 * 2
    24
    >>> falling(4, 1)  # 4
    4
    >>> falling(4, 0)
    1
    """
    fact = n
    i = 0    
    while i <= k:
        fact = fact * fact - 1
        i += 1
        n -= 1
    return fact
```

Comment: what is the problem with your code?

Comment: Note that `fact * fact - 1` is equivalent to `(fact * fact) - 1`. Not sure that's what you want.

Comment: @deadshot Beside the fact that it's totally wrong?

Comment: That doesn't help. Logic in my code is completely off. I need to understand the logic.

Comment: @Barmar what is wrong????

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def falling(n, k):
    """Compute the falling factorial of N to depth K.

    >>> falling(6, 3)  # 6 * 5 * 4
    120
    >>> falling(4, 3)  # 4 * 3 * 2
    24
    >>> falling(4, 1)  # 4
    4
    >>> falling(4, 0)
    1
    """
    
    if k == 0:
        return 1

    return_value = 1

    counter = 0

    while counter < k:
        return_value = return_value * (n-counter)
        counter += 1

    return return_value
```

Ignoring k=0 you have want to multiply k numbers starting with n and ending with n-k. The above loops k times and since i will increment by 1 starting from 0, you can simply subtract it from n to get the next number to multiply by.

Edit: Making sure k=0 is returning 1 always by returning early

Edit2: Removing built in range function

Edit3: making sure to go k deep

Comment: This is great. With one caveat, it's using a built-in function range.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding that you don't want to use that or is it simply that you would like more info on that built-in function?

Comment: Timbolt, I just want to use primitive operators and if/while loop. No built-in functions like range etc.

Comment: I changed it, is that what you want? I assume you dont want the range function to get a better understanding for the calculations? Otherwise it just makes it messier.

Comment: Timbolt, Thank you for trying to help. The problem is a bit trickier; it's asking you to do a factorial upto K times, Not For K times. So for N=6 and K=3 it works because N - K = 3 which is true because we want factorial of 6 upto 5, 4. However, what about N=4 and K=1? With N - K still 3, we will end up with 4 * 3 * 2 = 12 - which is what we don't want. We want 1 depth i.e. 4 * 1 = 4

Comment: oh yeah sorry that was just by brain glitching, you can just do counter < k instead of counter < n-k. Should do what you want now.

Comment: Great! Thanks Timbolt. For bad inputs we can also add:
```
 if k == 0:
        return 1
    elif k > n:
        return print("k cannot be greater than n")
```

Answer (score 0):

since you dont want a solution, but rather want why the code is failing, ill give you some pointers

Logic is wrong here is why

- fact is being updated every iteration,
- double check the while condition i < k or i <= k?

Comment: pointer 1) Yes, and I want to know how to preserve (accumulate) result.
pointer 2) code below by Timbolt solves k being 0 problem by returning static 1.

my problem here as your noticed. 1) how do I accumulate the total, if I have to or not using while loop? 2) or do a for loop K times with n -1 every iteration?

Comment: To preserve the value, simply use an other variable , it will look something like this res = res * fact, and after than you need to decrement fact by 1 every iteration, so fact = fact - 1 ( initialize res to 1 ) , also, you need to look exactly k times, so it should be i < k if  your k is 0 you can either return 0 or 1 before the loop based on what your preference is

Answer (score 0):

First you need generate numbers to apply multiplication on

e.g `# 6 * 5 * 4`
we get that by using

`range(n, k, -1)` => e.g for (n, k) = (6, 3) would be [6, 5, 4]

then accumulating list items products product with `reduce`.

````py
def falling(n, k):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, list(range(n, k, -1)))

# more readable

```python
def falling(n, k):
    from operator import mul
    return reduce(mul, list(range(n, k, -1)))
````

`lambda x, y: x * y` => just get the product of two number

in python 3.8+

you would use `math.prod()`

```
def factorial_with_depth(n, k):
    """Compute the falling factorial of n to depth k."""
    from math import prod  # python 3.8+
    return prod(range(n, k, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the ["falling factorial"](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials), also known as the "falling power". It's generally pronounced as "n to the k falling".

### Integer arguments

For positive integer arguments, it can be calculated as the ratio of factorials: `n! / (n - k)!`. In Python this translates to:

```py
import math

def falling(n: int, k: int) -> int:
    assert k >= 0
    return math.factorial(n) // math.factorial(n - k)
```

To illustrate:

```
>>> [falling(6, k) for k in range(6)]
[1, 6, 30, 120, 360, 720]
```

Alternatively, it can also be calculated by multiplying the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) "n choose k" by `n!`, i.e. `math.comb(n, k) * math.factorial(k)`.

### Real arguments

In case you have real arguments, the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) can be used, which extends the factorial to the real domain. Since floats can overflow, it is best to use the logarithm of the gamma function:

```py
def falling_real(x: float, n: int | float) -> float:
    return math.exp(math.lgamma(x + 1) - math.lgamma(x - n + 1))
```

For example:

```
>>> falling_real(math.e, math.pi)
2.7574468451854215
```

Note that this can result in slight numerical errors:

```
>>> [falling_real(6, k) for k in range(6)]
[1.0, 6.000000000000003, 30.000000000000057, 120.00000000000009, 360.0000000000007, 720.0000000000008]
```